# Can't remove Agent Software from OEM13c

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have "applied" Agent Software in my Oracle Cloud Control 13c. Agent was installed on previous servers and work fine. But now when I want to install it on new configured server, OEM tell me that "Agent Software Unavailable". But when I look to Setup -> Extensibility -> Self Update, there is this Agents status is "Apply". I can't remove or do anything from Action button. Also Size column is empty. How can I redownload or reapply this agent?

Comment: Size column being empty (`-`, a dash) is normal. Sounds like you tried to install an agent for a different platform.

Comment: I want to install Linux x86 64. There is the same platform Linux x86 64, but agent 13.1.0 and work normal. I need 13.2.0